# How can I get a child folder from a path

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to get a foldername from a path, for example, the param its the father path like: `$HOME/folderfather`, folderfather has one folder inside, `$HOME/folderfather/folderchild`.

I want to recieve for param the father path and save the name of child. `chfoldname=folderchild` like this

Comment: So like `echo "$HOME/folderfather/folderchild" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'` ?

Comment: Not clear at all. Do you want to find out the name of subfolder, or you already know its name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming there is **only one directory** inside your folderfather, the below could do it :

```
chfoldname=$(ls -l ${yourFatherPathVar} | grep '^d' | tail -1 | awk -F" " '{print $NF}')
```

Comment: `chfoldname=$(basename path/*/)` does the same in that case. This is useless use of ls, grep, tail and awk